# Delete multiple Inputs on click with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-select2

I paginated my Project (endless, without click) and when the next page is loaded, a input `select2 input` field in a Modal is getting replicated. So after a bit of scrolling I have couple duplicates.

[image: Looking like this]

So I tried to delete the duplicates like:

```
$(".modalOpen").click(function(){
  $('.theLangu1:eq(0)').next("span").remove();
  $('.theLangu1').children().find(...).remove();
  $('.theLangu1:eq(1)').remove();
  ...
 })
```

but nothing worked. The code looks like this in the console:

[image]

So the first one needs to stay alive but the rest has to be removed. (`$('.theLangu1:eq(0)').remove();` does remove everything except one but it also deletes the necessary one so it does not help).

Another Problem is that I have multiple `<input>` and other `select2` fields so its not done by simply removing everything (I tried). So it needs to be something in the direction `$(".theLangu1").children().find/next...`

Any jQuery expert here to tell me how to remove duplicates or all inputs except the first one?

Comment: Why not fix the actual problem?

Comment: yes I'm familiar with the "xyproblem" but this is to big to ask it here and I need to fix this soon. Its a workaround for the next days. have multiple jQuery versions loaded (yes I know there is the `noConflict` option and other things, I tried them all and nothing worked so far)  but again this is another story and its to complex... @epascarello

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `not` CSS psuedo-selector

```
$('.theLangu1').parent()
  .find(".theLangu1:not('.theLangu1:first-child')")
  .remove();
```

You can use the `not` JQuery method

```
 $('.theLangu1').parent()
   .find(".theLangu1").not(".theLangu1:first-child")
   .remove();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rwh7wd37/1/

Comment: really nice. Had to change it a little (class names) but this worked just fine. I appreciate that you took the time to make a JSFiddle ;)

Answer (score 1):

why not you are adding just a class to parent level say

```
$(".modalOpen").addClass('hideTheLangu1');
```

and maintain a `css` hierarchy affect

```
.modalOpen.hideTheLangu1 .theLangu1:nth-child(n+2) {
    display: none
}
```

so all the items having class `theLangu1` inside it will be hidden, so you js code will just add the class `hideTheLangu1`, and just remove the class whenever you need to show them again (if you have such use case). If you want to remove it completely from DOM, use take same approach and select all but the first one by jQuery selector (`$(".modalOpen").find(".theLangu1:nth-child(n+2)"`), and just invoke `remove()`, you don't need to do a loop to `each` item at all.

Comment: I tried to make your code run, but had to many difficulties. Looks like a solid solution but its not working for me right now. Still thanks for the answer, good explanation, I like that.

Answer (score 1):

You could loop through all of them, deleting them all but ignore the first

```
for(let i=0;i<$('.theLangu1').length;i++) {
    if(i!==0){
        $('.theLangu1').eq(i).remove();
    }
}
```

Or in pure jquery

`$('.theLangu1').not(':first').remove();`

Comment: I did not want to remove the "theLangu1" class, but the child of it. Still good solution would have to modify it a bit to make it work for my needs. Thanks anyway :)